# What is role of ending "/" in url?

Tags: jsp, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a project, built from a tutorial, in progress. It uses *Hibernate* and Java *Servlets*, locally, on a *Tomcat* server. I get different results with the following two urls:

- localhost:8080/MyProject/admin
- localhost:8080/MyProject/admin/

Either results in the display of the page `login.jsp` via forwarding executed in an implementation of `Servlet.Filter`:

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/admin/login.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

But the two pages seem to think they are at differing addresses. Within the JSP page is a link for the css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css">
```

When I view the "page source" for the two URLs, here are the addresses that show up when mousing over the above links:

```
localhost:8080/css/styles.css
localhost:8080/MyProject/css/styles.css
```

So, the `styles.css` file is only found if I use the address `localhost:8080/MyProject/admin/`.

Is there a way to have the `Servlet.Filter` set the correct/intended address such that a user can either add or omit the "/" and still arrive at the same location with the same functionality?

I'm having trouble locating syntax info pertaining to the "/"--and would love to have a link to background info or explanations.

Comment: In response to the question closure--I'm curious how the linked question pertains. That question and it's solution involves a prefix-slash, and my situation involves a suffix-slash. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [an article I found](https://searchfacts.com/url-trailing-slash/), it looks like a folder can either be addressed with a "/" at the end or not. It's not a settled situation. The main thing is to be consistent.

Since the form with the slash at the end is being interpreted correctly by the Servlets code, and the other isn't, I have reached the conclusion that the best plan would be to stick with the slash version, and use 301 redirects to handle the non-slash case.